# How can I use a local JSON object as a data source for jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a local JSON object formatted like this:

```
[{
    "id": "58",
    "country_code": "UK",
    "title": "Legal Director",
    "pubdate": "2012-03-08 00:00:00",
    "url": "http://..."
},{
    "id": "59",
    "country_code": "UK",
    "title": "Solutions Architect,",
    "pubdate": "2012-02-23 00:00:00",
    "url": "http://..."
},{
    // ....more of the same......
}]
```

I would like to set this as the data source for a jQuery [datatable](http://datatables.net/blog/Extended_data_source_options_with_DataTables) and have tried this:

```
testdata = '{{ jobsJSON | raw }}'; //twig template tag
console.log(testdata);
$('#test').dataTable({
    "aoData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "country_code" },
        { "mDataProp": "title" },
        { "mDataProp": "pubdate" },
        { "mDataProp": "url" }
    ]
});
```

The DataTables plugin loads and attempts to draw the table but gives the error 'No data available in table'

I am not making an AJAX call and just want to access the JSON object from a local JS variable.

Comment: Does `console.log(testdata);` give you a string or an array/object? (use `typeof testdata` if you cannot tell the difference.

Comment: its a string. I have also tried using $.parseJSON() on it.

Comment: thanks - this sorted it. testdata = $.parseJSON( '{{ jobsJSON | raw }}');

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The property to supply your own data is `aaData` NOT `aoData`:

```
testdata = [{"id":"58",...}]; // local object

$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "country_code" },
        { "mDataProp": "title" },
        { "mDataProp": "pubdate" },
        { "mDataProp": "url" }
    ]
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8JmF/228/)

Comment: Thanks. It was a combination of this and the json was not being parsed correctly: testdata = $.parseJSON( '{{ jobsJSON | raw }}');

Comment: I know this is an old reply but how do I get to show the column titles? It's currently empty. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali Add a title attribute after your mDataProp to set the column titles. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486279/119829

Comment: if i have another var that i want to set as column, can i do it without adding that variable to that `testdata` json?

Answer (score 1):

I encoutered the same problem, solution is like this:
Place `$('#list_table').dataTable` code in `setTimeout` function to postpone dataTable application for 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout("$('#list_table').dataTable ...." , 5000);
```

I noticed that apply dataTable plugin in firebug after the table is loaded, it doesn't show error as "No data available in table".