# Jquery datatables not showing column headings

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am following [the example here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html). Using an array containing object.

I create my array in a for loop like this

```
historyArray[i] = {
    "User": strUserName, 
    "Timestamp" : date.toString(), 
    "Latitude" : point.lat, 
    "Longitude" : point.lng
};
```

My datatable implementation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dynamic').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="report"></table>');
    $('#report').dataTable({
        "aaData": historyArray,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "User" },
            { "mDataProp": "Timestamp" },
            { "mDataProp": "Latitude" },
            { "mDataProp": "Longitude" }
        ],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
        }
    }); 
});
```

I am getting the data correctly but with no column headings, am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your `<table>` element like this:

```
<table id=report>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

That way the headers are created. If you click view source on the example page you will see the same implementation.

Comment: oh, thought it would pull dynamically.. anyway this worked :) cheers

Comment: @VinceLowe I think it depends on how the data is structured. I've used Datatables extensively and I had columns show up dynamically once in a while. For example, if you use gridview (c#) and then apply datatables to it, it will take the headers from gridview. Also if you specify your own headers you can add filters (like dropdowns or textboxes).

Comment: I hardcoded as above, but it seems to me that you should not have to spell the headers out in the html... am posting [this re: dynamically generating headers](http://alanhollis.com/datatables-net-dynamic-column-headings-ajax-request/) in the hope of either helping someone or getting it to work at some point...

Comment: While this does work, it's the wrong approach and should be discouraged in favor of the configuration option user1429980 shows  .

Answer (score 42):

If you're passing in data in the form of an array of objects, then you'll need to specify the titles of each column manually:

```
data = this.SearchController.resultSet;
this.$tableContainer.dataTable({
    data:    data,
    columns: [
    {
        data: "H",
        title: "Thickness"
    },
    {
        data: "InstanceId",
        title: "Instance ID"
    }]
});
```

**Note: this will *not* require you to specify headers in your `table` element**.  All you need is an empty `<table>`, and this will work.
Documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Looks like it suits all scenarios.

Comment: thanks, I wonder why this is not mentioned for the particular example in the datatables documentation? I've spent 30 minutes trying to fix it reading the docs until I got to your response

Comment: Thank you so much! I was scouring the datatables documentation for this but could not find it.

Comment: @ViceLowe can you swap the accepted answer to this as this actually works..

Comment: I like this answer over the chosen one because it keeps the linking between data and columns in one place. I've had issues at my companies where the headers are specified in the HTML and they get the wrong data because the ordering is different in the JS. This makes that much less likely.

Answer (score 3):

If your passing in a data array and your table element is hidden at the time that you initialize your datatable then all of the thead/tfoot elements, and every child element, gets a height:0px inline style added to them.

Make sure to show() the table element right before initializing your datatable unless you want to go back after and change all the height styles of all the elements.

```
// unhide your table
$('#dtableid').show();

// initialize your datatable
$('#dtableid').DataTable({ 
   data: data,
   // .. other init options
})
```

Comment: So many years later, yet this worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below will create headers dynamically

```
$('#dtableid').DataTable({
  "aaData": [
    {
      "abc": "123",
      "xyz": 456
    },
     {
      "abc": "123",
      "xyz": 456
    }
  ],
  "aoColumns": [
    {
      "mData": "abc",
      "title": "ABC",
      "bSortable": true
    },
    {
      "mData": "xyz",
      "title": "XYZ",
      "bSortable": true
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

we can also print the datatable column header like this :

```
"columns": [
    {
        "data": "Sno", "name": "Sno", "autoWidth": true,"title":"S.No"
    }
    ,
    {
        "data": "Result", "name": "Result", "autoWidth": true, "title": "Result",  render: function (data1, type, full, meta) {
            if (full.Count > 0) {
                return '<a style="color:blue" href="#" class="point"  onclick="ApprovalBreakUp(this)" value="' + data1 + '">' + data1 + '</a>'
            }
            else {
                return '<label>' + data1 + '</label>'
            }
        }

    }
    ,
    {
        "data": "Count", "name": "Count", "autoWidth": true, "title": "Count"
    }
```