# Jquery datatables does not display the column headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

This is linked to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417072/jquery-datatables-not-showing-column-headings). However, my case is a bit different. I would like to implement the same datatables example from the other question which is [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html). As you can see you have to pass the column names to be able to initialize the table headers like below

```
 "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ]
```

The problem is that I would not know the header names beforehand as they will change. I've tried initializing the column names when I get the data from ajax like below using a 3rd variable (see where it says 'pay attention to this line' but this doesn't work.

```
            //PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
            var columnsHeaders = [];


      var ab = $('#dynamicScenarioTable').DataTable({
              "bDestroy": true,
              "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
              "ajax": {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "dynamicScenario.htm",
                    "data": tags,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "dataSrc": function(json){
                          //PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
                          columnsHeaders.push({"data": json.header });
                          return json.vals;
                    },
                    "error": function(exception)
                    {
                       displayMessageOnError();
                    }
               },  
                //PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
               "columns":  [columnsHeaders],

               tableTools: tableDefaultS.tableTools
      });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you know the data? It is either a dynamic input, from a form of some kind, or as part of the AJAX request. You should be able to get the headers.

Comment: since the number of column fields as well as their names will change. I can loop through in the json file though to find out their number as I've demonstrated in the example above. However, I don't know how to assign that to the columns field after

Comment: If the headers are changing, then the data is too. Why wouldn't you just re-create the table?

Comment: does that mean that I will have to build the table dynamically by appending tr and tds and then call datatables?

Comment: No necessarily, there may be another way. Just giving you other options.

Comment: well, I know the options when I will have to just update the table with ajax but when the columns change is there any ajax way of populating the table except nuking the whole table and recreating it..that's my problem

Comment: do you have the ability to have the code that is generating the table header layout, add a "data-source" attribute to the th tags?  Is so, I think I have an idea for you.

Comment: You could append/remove `<td>` tags until the column count is the same... I almost prefer the nuke idea, you will still probably have to recall dataTable anyway, the data is different.

Comment: at the minute I am nuking the whole table and inserting the data manually and then reinitializing the table which is causes additional rendering time

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-source attribute to the TH tags that are built on your table header.  You can then have jQuery read those and construct the array to send into the DataTable constructor.

```
<tr>
    <th data-source="name">Name</th>
    <th data-source="position">Postion</th>
    <th data-source="start_date">Start Date</th>
</tr>
```

Then in your JavaScript do something like this to construct the array

```
var columnsHeaders = [];
$("#dynamicScenarioTable thead th").each(function() {
    colmnsHeaders.push(
        {
            data : $(this).data("source")
        }
    );
});

// construct your DataTable after this
```

Comment: I can't do it since I don't know neither the names nor the number of columns beforehand.

Comment: so what is building out your column headers for the table?

Comment: well I can know the headers in the ajax response. Your code is similar to what I've pasted above. I can push the headers to the array in the ajax but then I can't assign this array to the datatables "columns" setting for some reason. Probably because its asynch

Comment: You example is just trying to tell DataTables what the bindings for the column's are.  It is not creating the header columns.  I actually just looked at the [DataTable docs](http://datatables.net/manual/options) and it looks like you can use the html5 attribute data-class-name on the th that DataTables will automatically read and that would negate my whole example above.  The object you are sending into the DataTables constructor is already bound before your update your array from your ajax call.  It is only seeing the empty array and would produce a js error.

Comment: I don't know neither the header names nor the their count before my ajax request. I can know this info only in the ajax response where I it will be too late to construct the th of the table since I should have already assigned some value to the "column" feature of datatables. If I want to follow your approach I need to get the data with ajax first and then construct the table which is the same as nuking the table and recreating it but my intention is to build the table within the same ajax call as above.