# DataTable column names is invisible in header of table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

The data table is shown correctly but `DataTable` column names are invisible in header of table but accordingly to this link [[example]](https://datatables.net/manual/data/) there are no mistakes. Which way possible to show column names?
HTML index.php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data2 = [
        {
          "xx": "50",
          "yy": "30"
        },
        {
          "xx": "30",
          "yy": "20"
        }
      ];
      var table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
        columns: [
          { data: "xx" }, 
          { data: "yy" }
        ],
        data: data2
      })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="tbl" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: A quick google for "datatables missing column names" goes to [this datatables.net forum page](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30688/missing-column-names) with a link to an example that basically states you have to provide a `title` with your column definition.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `DataTables` before so I had to look around before I found a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417072/jquery-datatables-not-showing-column-headings) that states,

> If you're passing in data in the form of an array of objects, then
> you'll need to specify the titles of each column manually:

Hence, the below `cols` variable sets some meaningless column titles to illustrate the above statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data = [
        { "xx":80, "yy":30 },
        { "xx":30, "yy":20 },
        { "xx":28, "yy":560 },
        { "xx":340, "yy":120 },
        { "xx":130, "yy":820 },
        { "xx":350, "yy":920 },
        { "xx":3240, "yy":270 },
        { "xx":330, "yy":9720 },
        { "xx":4530, "yy":65420 },
        { "xx":860, "yy":30 },
        { "xx":30, "yy":230 },
        { "xx":238, "yy":5760 },
        { "xx":4340, "yy":120 },
        { "xx":1730, "yy":8920 },
        { "xx":350, "yy":920 },
        { "xx":3240, "yy":2740 },
        { "xx":3330, "yy":9720 },
        { "xx":4530, "yy":65420 }
      ];
      var cols=[
        { data: "xx", title:"Banana" }, 
        { data: "yy", title:"Mango" }
      ];
      var args={
        searching: true, 
        paging: true, 
        info: false,
        data:data,
        columns:cols
      };
      
      $('#dttbl').show();
      var table = $('#dttbl').DataTable(args)
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="//nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="dttbl" width="100%">
</table>
```

To avoid having to manually add your own title to each you could do some simple array mangling to add the values held in each child object, like this:

```
  cols.forEach( obj=>{
    obj.title=obj.data
  })
```