# How to populate data tables with the json string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I successfully getting the data table populated if I use the `sAjaxSource = "filepath/file"`

However if I pass the PHP json data and try to collect it its not populating the data in the datatable,

How can I directly use the json data without calling the data from objects.txt file. ?

```
json_data  = { "aaData": [
    {
        "Rendering_engine": "Trident",
        "Browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
        "Platforms": "Win 95+",
        "Engine_Version": "4",
        "CSS_Grade": " b"

    },
    {
        "Rendering_engine": "rident",
        "Browser": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
        "Platforms": "Win 95+",
        "Engine_Version": "5",
        "CSS_Grade": " a"

    }
] }
```

**php code**

```
$r = //sql query    
$ma['aaData'] =$r;
                        $data = json_encode($ma);
                        var_dump($data);
```

**script**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var json_data_chk =  <?php echo($data); ?>;
        var json_data = JSON.stringify(json_data_chk);
        alert(json_data);
// code     
var sImageUrl = "img/";


        var oTable = $('#hidden-table-info').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
           "sAjaxSource": "objects.txt",
            "bServerSide": false,
             "aoColumns": [
                {
                   "mDataProp": null,
                   "sClass": "control center",
                   "sDefaultContent": '<img src="'+sImageUrl+'details_open.png'+'">'
                },
                { "mDataProp": "Rendering_engine" },
                { "mDataProp": "Browser" },
                { "mDataProp": "Platforms" },

            ],
// code

    </script>
```

**EDIT:** 
 `json_data` is the variable that is having the same json data as objects.txt but instead of calling the file i want to use the data from this variable

Comment: If the data is obtained with an ajax call then you should set `bServerSide: true` and give the url of the ajax request to `sAjaxSource`. ie `sAjaxSource: $url`

Comment: The data is within the variable and need to collect it... I am able to do it that way form the file. but want to get it directly from the variable instead of writing to some file

Comment: @Hamid `json_data` is the variable that is havind the same json data as objects.txt but instead of calling the file i want to use the data from this variable

Comment: In that case, you can always construct the table dom and then call $().dataTable(); on it.

Comment: Also, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9669812/2139684

Comment: Thanks Buddy ... for the source and ans.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this instruction

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": "json_data"
} );
```

or this one :

```
 "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "type": "POST"
  }
```

Reference :https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax