# Jquery DataTable multiple filtrering on a single column doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I build a datatable in my jquery like this :

```
var ticketDataTable = $("#ticketDataTable").DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: function(data) {
                data.ticketStatusFilter = ketStatusCheckboxes.filter(':checked')
                    .map(function() { return this.value; }).get()
                    .join(';')
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { 
                 name: "ticket.ticketNumber",
                 data: "0.ticketNumber" 
            },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },        
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { }
        ],
        bSortCellsTop: true,
        dom: 'rt<lp>',
        order: [[2, "desc"]]    // Sort by descending date
    });
```

All columns are constructed in the same way. Then, i use sumoSelect plugin to create a dropdown list with checkboxes to do a multiple filter.

```
$("table#ticketDataTable thead tr th#multiSelectFilter").find("select").SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
```

It works well. Then, when the input change (when i check choices), i do this :

```
var arr = $("table#ticketDataTable thead tr th#multiSelectFilter").find("select")[0].sumo.getSelStr();
```

I get a result like this : `"FIRST|SECOND|THIRD"` or `"SECOND"` or `"FIRST|SECOND"`.

```
ticketDataTable.column(5).search(arr,true,true).draw();
```

But it works only with one choice. If i have more than one (like "FIRST|SECOND"), it doesn't work.

Comment: you would have to create a custom filters and use it to filter accordingly.. check this https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html , let me know if you need more help

Comment: yeah, but i don't want to filter on number column but on text/string column.

Comment: thats just a example. You have to change your logic accordingly.. Also that function will run for each row, So return true will make that row visible return false will remove it.. you need to write a logic saying if the column value is eithre this or that or that.. based on your multiple selection and then return true or false accordingly

Comment: i do it but when i call ticketDataTable.draw() nothing appends ! is it the parameter serverside = true ?

Comment: OMG!! didnt see that code... server side true is complex.. so tel me do you want to filter only on the data available on UI or it shld consider even the server data too??

Comment: filter data on ui.

Comment: then you can remove the server side true for that moment, then filter by calling draw.

Comment: sorry it also consider the server data because when i remove nothing appends and my data doesn't load without the parameter ...

Comment: I meant this way.. let  your code be as it is, Just before calling the `draw()` to filter the data, programatically set the server side to false then call the `draw()` this will not do a server call. Then after the filtering is done set back the server call to true.

Comment: how can i set the server side to false ?

Comment: `ticketDataTable.context[0].bAjaxDataGet = false; ` in your case this must work

Comment: didn't work, nothing happened

Comment: If you are getting data only once and then want to do sorting , filtering and stuff on only that data alone you can always get the data from server by ajax and store in some variable and then feed this variable data to datatables. So your datatables must use a local data and not server data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve it. I put new data in my ajax request. I use it in my server side to do my request. Then i change the data every click on my filter and i relaunch the request.

Works Fine !

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to **add a custom filter** and then call the table `draw()` function to filter out the necessary data. You will place the logic inside this custom filter.

So from what I can see is you have a multi select and you want to select all the rows where column 5 has either of the values from the multi-select. Here is the brief idea.

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        if (settings.nTable.id === "ticketDataTable") { // apply this fiter only to your ticketDataTable table.
            return CheckIfRowIsValid(data[5]); // data[5] will give you current row column idex 5's value.
        }
        else { //filter function not applicable to other datatables other than ticketDataTable so do nothing.
            return true;
        }
    }
   );

    function CheckIfRowIsValid(value) {
        var multiSelectArray = []; // get all the values from multi select.

        if ($.inArray(value, multiSelectArray) < 0) {
            return false;         //if value is not found in array return false as you dont have to show the row.
        }
        else {
            return true;          //return true to keep the row visible.
        }
    }
```

So as you can see, the **custom logic will be fired once for each row** and just by saying return true or false you can keep or remove the rows. `This example just concentrates on single column with multiple possible values` . You can extend it to work on multiple columns too. just by adding else if's for each column.

Now everytime you want to filter the table just call the `ticketDataTable.draw()`

Comment: ticketDataTable.context[0].bAjaxDataGet = false; doesn't work, nothing happened

Comment: @DyM If you are getting data only once and then want to do sorting , filtering and stuff on only that data alone you can always get the data from server by ajax and store in some variable and then feed this variable data to datatables. So your datatables must use a local data and not server data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669812/how-can-i-use-a-local-json-object-as-a-data-source-for-jquery-datatables